# How to drop column named `

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I managed to create a column in my MySQL database named ` (the backtick character).  How can I delete it?  Is there a way to escape the backtick character in a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting the [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html) to use [ANSI_QUOTES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) and then dropping the column that way:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES';

ALTER TABLE "schema"."table" DROP COLUMN "`";
```

Comment: Will that set the `sql_mode` globally or only for my current session?

Comment: It can be set globally or per session. The example above sets it at the session level.